# Java - When using the replace() method, there is a space between the replaced letter in a word. How do I make it where there is no space?

Tags: java, string

So I am I wrote a method to replace all char's in a string, and it works. However if the letter I want to replace is sandwiched in a word, there is a space in place of the replaced letter, so the one word is now two. Here is an example

String str is `Hello World` . The character I want to make blank is `o` . My code will return this string `Hell   W rld`. How do I change my method so it outputs `Hell Wrld`

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeAll("Hello World", 'e'));

}
public static String removeAll(String str, char letter) {  
    String replace = str.replace(letter,' ');
    return replace;
}
```

Comment: You explicitly told it to replace the character with a blank space. `str.replace(letter,' ');` Just remove the space from the second parameter. `str.replace(letter,'');`

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing passed character with space in your replace method.

Replace char with `CharSequence` version lile `str = str.replace("X", "");`

"X" here is just an example you can pass your char and convert to string and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace("o", "");
```

Replace your intended letter with empty String.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String replace = str.replace(letter,' ');
```

to

```
String replace = str.replace(letter,"");
```

Otherwise, you are putting a white space where 'o' used to be. If you want to completely burn that character, replace it with an empty character.